# Schengen visa sponsored by my father

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning on travelling to Finland to visit a friend whom I've met over the internet. I am currently unemployed and just passed my national boards. I want to take a vacation to spend time with my friend and, possibly, to go to Paris, France to visit iconic landmarks.

I have read that, in order to sponsor, the person must be in the Schengen Area. My dad works abroad and is willing to cover all of my expenses. Would this be valid grounds for getting a Schengen visa?

I have no intention of working or looking for a job there; I am just going there for a trip.

Plus, if my friend *whom I've never met* is willing to cover my expenses in order to visit their country, and submits all documents required, would it be enough?

Comment: My friend will be my host.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Answer (score 4):

Put yourself in the shoes of the other. If you were the officer judging, which bits of your story would trigger red flags? Let's have a try: no job, just out of school , no independent source of income, never seen the "Internet" friend. Without knowing your nationality, that already sounds like a "Reject".

Answer (score 1):

The visa officials will try to let **genuine tourists** in and to keep **illegal immigrants** out. You will have to convince the officials that you are a genuine tourist.

- Sponsorship or an invitation letter are not required for tourism. A reasonable explanation what you want to do is required.
- However, they do want to know who pays for your trip and why. It is entirely normal that a parent or older relative pays for the trip of a young adult, but only if that person can really afford it. **Is the money a gift or an investment?** If the whole family empties their savings accounts to send one young relative abroad, that looks like illegal immigration.
- They will also want to know if you have ties to your homeland which make it appear more likely that you will return. The best case is a stable, well-paid job, but they realize that this isn't always the case for young adults.

Looking at the snow in Finland and the art in Paris is entirely normal for a tourist. Visiting an internet friend is not normal for a tourist unless the tourist can *really* afford to spend that money.